# how to get intermediate weights and bias with keras function

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to get intermediate output from my own image, therefore I use K.function to create a function that generates intermediate output base on https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer :

```
function = k.function(model.inputs, [model.layers[x].output])

output = function ([processed_image])
```

It goes well, but when I try to get intermediate weights and bias like this:

`function = k.function([model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]], [model.layers[x].get_weights()[0]])`

This is not working, and I am using keras vgg model, can someone help me on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include the error that you are getting?

Comment: weights and biases are constants, there is no need to "get them" using K.function, just call model.layers[0].get_weights()